# How to use a list of strings in a switch statement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm making a console application with a siri-like AI that responds to your questions using random but appropriate answers. I'm storing these answers and valid questions the user can ask inside of lists, but I need a way to check what questions are being asked by the user. I'm right now using if statements, but I'm afraid that it is going to start causing issues later on, as well as taking up more space than is needed. It looks like this:

```
if (question[0] == Console.ReadLine())
        {
            Console.Clear();
            randIndex = rand.Next(0, 3);
            Console.WriteLine(state[randIndex]);
            Discussion();
        }
        if (question[1] == Console.ReadLine())
        {
            Console.Clear();
            randIndex = rand.Next(0, 4);
            Console.WriteLine(joke[randIndex]);
            Discussion();
        }
        if (question[2] == Console.ReadLine())
        {
            Console.Clear();
            randIndex = rand.Next(0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(yourName[randIndex]);
            Discussion();
        }
```

I'm trying however to use switch statements, and this is how i'm doing it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < question.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (question[i])
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    randIndex = rand.Next(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine(state[randIndex]);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The only issue here is that i'm getting an error under the "1" which says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string". I also tried replacing 
"Case 1" with "case question[0]:" and I get an error which says "A constant value is expected". Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the type of `question`?

Comment: the  message is so explicit you are comparing the question to an int I mean a string to an int

Comment: I guess it should be either `case "1":` or `case "SomeContent":`?

Comment: "question" is the list that stores valid user questions to input.

Comment: You cannot compare the string obtained from question[i] to integer `1`. Change `case 1` to `case "1"` (or whatever string value you expect).

Comment: You are trying to compare a *string* that contains a *textual question* with an integer. That's what the error says very clearly. For example "Random Text Isn't AI" can't be converted to an integer

Comment: You should explain what you want to achieve with the `switch-case`. If the user can add any question there, then a `switch-case` is the wrong approach since you can't cover every possibility.

Comment: The problem with me actually doing something like "case "1" is that the string that correlates with that case is a long sentence, so I don't want to put whole sentences in for each case. I need an integer to represent each spot of the list instead. That's why I also tried "case question[0].

Comment: Well if it's about the spot of the list then you simply need a `switch-case` for the index of your list `i`:
`switch(i){ case 1: ... break; case 2: ... break; ...}`

Comment: You should then use a Dicionary. See @TimSchmelter and Dmitry Bychenko answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this. I hope it will work for you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < question.Count; i++)
{
    if (question[i] == Console.ReadLine())
    {
        Console.Clear();
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:

                randIndex = rand.Next(0, 3);
                Console.WriteLine(state[randIndex]);

                break;

            case 1:
                randIndex = rand.Next(0, 4);
                Console.WriteLine(joke[randIndex]);
                break;

            case 2:
                randIndex = rand.Next(0, 2);
                Console.WriteLine(yourName[randIndex]);
                break;
        }
        Discussion();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I sugest using *dictionary* and combine all the cases into one:

```
  Dictionary<string, int> jokes = new Dictionary<string, int>(
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
      { "question1", 3 },
      { "question2", 4 },
      { "question3", 2 },
      .... 
    };

  ...

  int randMax = 0;

  if (jokes.TryGetValue(Console.ReadLine(), out randMax)) {
    Console.Clear();
    randIndex = rand.Next(0, randMax);
    Console.WriteLine(state[randIndex]);
    Discussion();
  }
```

Comment: I'll definitely look into this but I don't understand this code yet.

Answer (score 2):

The collection `question` stores strings not integers. So you can't use

```
switch (question[i])
{
    case 1: // maybe "1", only you know
```

I'd suggest to use a different approach. It seems the only difference is the max value for `Random.Next` according to the input of the user. So i would use a `Dictionary<string, int>`:

```
var textMaxValDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"sampletext1", 3}, {"sampletext2", 4}, {"sampletext1", 2}
};
```

Now you only need this:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int maxValue;
bool inputMatchesOne = textMaxValDictionary.TryGetValue(input, out maxValue);

if(inputMatchesOne)
{
   Console.Clear();
   int randIndex = rand.Next(0, maxValue);
   Console.WriteLine(joke[randIndex]);
   Discussion();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tell user that was wrong...");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already stated yourself, if you solve the issue this way, the code will keep growing for every question you add.

To prevent this, you could use a dictionary to look up the valid responses:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> questions= new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
questions["What's your name?"] = new string[] { "Siri", "Cortana", "Google", "Alexa" };

string asked = Console.ReadLine();
string[] responses;
if (!questions.TryGetValue(asked, out responses)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("I don't know what to say man");
    return;
}

int index = rand.Next(0, responses.Length);
Console.WriteLine(responses[index]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not really familiar with dictionaries yet. That's why I'm using if statements or switch statements.

Comment: @Aazo5 That's ok, take things step by step.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but only using C#7 (available with VS2017). Then your code could become something like:

```
switch (Console.ReadLine())
{
    case var s when s == questions[0]:
        Console.Clear();
        randIndex = rand.Next(0, 3);
        Console.WriteLine(state[randIndex]);
        Discussion();
        break;
    case var s when s == question[1]:
        Console.Clear();
        randIndex = rand.Next(0, 4);
        Console.WriteLine(joke[randIndex]);
        Discussion();
        break;
    case ...
}
```

But this syntax really doesn't offer any benefits over multiple `if` statements. So you would be far better off following the advice in other questions and using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement is not the only "problem" with that piece of code. You could make things a lot easier when not duplicat code for example.

Something like this would make it more easy to maintain.
Assuming you state, joke, etc. properties are of type `List<string>` this could loke like this (and this is just an idea which could be made better/shorter with e.g. using methods).

```
var allowedQuestions = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    { "question 1", state },
    { "question 1", joke },
    { "question 1", yourName }
};

var input = Console.ReadLine();

if(allowedQuestions.ContainsKey(input))
{
    var answers = allowedQuestions[input];
    var randIndex = rand.Next(0, answers.Count - 1);
    Console.WriteLine(answers[randIndex]);
    Discussion();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("no answer");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the club ;-)

Comment: Oh, guess I needed to long for writing an answer :(